# Xcode 4.2 + c++0x/libc++ cannot find iostream

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, c++11, llvm, libc++

I'm using Macbook 1g, Snow Leopard.

Few days ago i installed xcode 4.2 and made a test project for c++0x.

I set LLVM 3.0 as c++ compiler, C++ Language Dialect as C++0x and C++ Standard Library as libc++.

but when building, error occured.

```
"iostream" file not found
```

I find it most bewildering. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you hit the "run" button, does it compile and run anyway?

Comment: Oh, i found it. libc++ as standard library requires OS X Lion! (...) I changed libc++ to libstdc++ and it compiled successfully.

Comment: I don't know about running under Xcode, but if you want to try clang+libc++ on Snow Leopard with a command line interface, you can try the "get it" directions at http://libcxx.llvm.org/ .

Comment: @Prin_E congratulations on figuring it out. Please post this as an *answer* and accept it to mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 5):

"I changed libc++ to libstdc++".  How?  Where is this setting?  Apple documentation says "simply set "C++ Standard Library Type" in the build settings to ... "  Build settings is long and I don't see the place to set.  Thanks.

Edit - Nothing like a nap to clear the head.

Be sure to make the file name suffix of the implementation file to be ".mm".

Project->Build Settings->Apple LLVM compiler 3.1-Language-> Then:
C++ Language Dialect->C++11 (or whatever option)
C++ Standard Library->libstdc++

And don't forget this last one!
Compile Sources as->Objective-C++

Comment: Make sure to set the `Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C` option to `Apple LLVM Compiler 3.x`, otherwise the options listed above won't appear.

That said, does anyone know why the Apple LLVM compiler is the only one that lets one specify the C++ standard library?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

Oh, i found it. libc++ as standard library requires OS X Lion! (...) I changed libc++ to libstdc++ and it compiled successfully.

Comment: Which probably means I cannot use c++0x on leopard? I cannot include #include <type_traits> if I do this

Comment: Just change the compiler to Apple LLVM and set the standard library as per the other answers in this thread.

Comment: Also see `User-Defined -> CLANG_XX_LIBRARY`