# 'iostream' file not found error occur in xcode 4.5?

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, xcode

i m practising C++. i just add c++ files in XCode and write some string splitting functionality in it. After that i include that C++ file i.e. extension of .mm file in my AppDelegate file and call function from .h file of C++ class. But i found one static error in red line which is **'iostream' file not found** . I used latest XCode version 4.5 and iOS 6.0. Please see screen shot of my error or xcode screen.
[image]

I m tried to modify my code as per given [link](http://www.mytechspace.com/2012/03/solved-integrate-c-code-with-objective.html) information but no success. :(

also i followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913637/xcode-4-2-c0x-libc-cannot-find-iostream) information as well, but result is same.

Thanks
iHungry

Comment: Don't `#include` C++ code from a header that has to work in Objective-C. (Your problem could be that you are including `StringSplit.h` in a `.m` file somewhere.)

Comment: @Mankarse, sorry i m not getting you. I have to include C++ class file in Objective-C class. I do this but it throwing additional error to me .

Comment: If `StringSplit.h` is Objective-C++ (as opposed to Objective-C), you should only include it from `.mm` files and never `.m` files.

Comment: See my screenshot. I have have two files of C++ of one class .h and .mm files. I include StringSplit.h file in AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: Also i try to change extension of AppDelegate.m file to AppDelegate.mm but no success

Comment: That header contains nothing that depends on `iostream`, so you should include it in the .mm file instead of the .h file.

Comment: don't use double-underscore names. those are reserved to the standard library implementation.

Comment: @phresnel, thanks, i will keep remember it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iostream.h, fstream.h cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225277/iostream-h-fstream-h-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Objective C` having `.m` extensions for its implementation files. If you want to use `C++` in `Objective C` it should have `.mm` extensions. you can include `C++` header files in your `.mm` file. But if you want to include your `C++` header files in your `.h` file, you need to check `macro` for that, like

```
#ifdef __cplus
#include <iostream>
#endif
```

But, I haven't tried any functions by including `C++` header file in `.h` file. Hope it helps.

Comment: YOu can even use C files wiht .C

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, yes we can. But as per my requirement i have to do such functionality in C++.

Comment: What extra are you getting in C++ that is missing in the combination of C and Obj-C ? If I can help you :p