# Linked library can't find `std::`

Tags: ios, objective-c

Example error:

```
"std::string::data() const", referenced from:
```

The link command is doing:

```
-lstdc++
```

And I have the C++ Standard Library set to `libstdc++` in Build Settings.

Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: it's an Objective-C++ project I suppose

Comment: change your implementation file extension from .m to .mm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376525/iostream-file-not-found-error-occur-in-xcode-4-5

Comment: This is an Objective-C iPad app that is using a `.a` library. The library was compiled with std C++.

Comment: To be clear, this is in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I added the link flag `-lstdc++`, XCode 5 overwrites that option. I had to add a dummy C++ class (`.h` and `.mm` files) to get Xcode to use the std c++. [Got the tip here](http://www.zeroc.com/forums/help-center/6103-icetouch-xcode-5-dp.html)