# iostream file not found in xcode 5

Tags: c++, ios7, xcode5, zxing

I am using ZXing library with version 2.2 for QRCode scan on xcode version 5.0.2 
One of the file named "Counted.h" contains #include . 
All the libraries are added and header path is also set as mentioned in different questions.

I have a ZXing integrated stand alone project which is compiling successfully but facing errors when trying to integrate with my project.

It is showing an error "'iostream' file not found" on building the project.

I am also using Tesseract and SQLCipher libraries.

Probably there is some issue in build settings.
Can anyone tell me if I am missing out anything??

Comment: Have you tried look at these questions?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376525/iostream-file-not-found-error-occur-in-xcode-4-5

https://discussions.apple.com/message/22142661#22142661

Comment: Also, if you use a C++ library along with Objective C, you might have to include a flag in the project settings. I forget which flag, but pretty sure you need to do it.

Comment: I tried to put flag -ObjC++ in other linker flag. It dint work. Please let me know which flag it is and where to add it ?

Comment: Also sometimes with compiler changes and all iostream error goes away and i get 20 other errors in allocator.h, new_allocator.h, basic_string.h. errors are                                   Expected member name or ‘;’ after declaration specifiers
Expected an identifier or template-id after ‘::’
Please help.. I'm stuck at this since few days. Thanks