# When including a C++ header file from an Objective-C header file it has compiling error, iostream not found

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

TestViewController.h/TestViewController.mm

HelloWorld.h/HelloWorld.cpp

If I include "HelloWorld.h" into TestViewController.mm it compiles well. When I include "HelloWorld.h" into TestViewController.h it prompts an error: 'iostream' file not found.

My HelloWorld.h code is a simple standard cpp file.

```
#ifndef __MixedCppTest__HelloWorld__
#define __MixedCppTest__HelloWorld__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class HelloWorld {


public:
    HelloWorld();
    ~HelloWorld();
};
#endif /* defined(__MixedCppTest__HelloWorld__) */
```

Comment: Objective-C and C++ are not compatible. You'll need to use Objective-C++.

Comment: Additional I can change Compile Source As to Objective-c++, but there is another way to solve it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I include "HelloWorld.h" into TestViewController.h it prompt
>   error: 'iostream' file not found….

Is there any Objective-C files which imports TestViewController.h?
At the stage of preprocessing header file becomes a part(along with the source file) of a translation unit, and if you're asking to include such header (with c++ libraries inclusion and c++ class definition) to Objective-C source file - then no, it's impossible. If you searching a way to compile and link .cpp and .m source files to one binary, you could make .mm wrapper unit to wire them together.

Comment: The key is if you import cpp file indirectly, you should change all files to objective-c++ compiled mode on the import chain. My problem is AppDelegate.m is not be changed to .mm

Comment: Are you trying to solve any specific problem or just making a reconnaissance? In the second case it's easy to set yourself an unsolvable task which just do not have to be solved at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can use macros

```
#ifdef __cplus
 // TODO Code
#endif
```

Reference: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376525/iostream-file-not-found-error-occur-in-xcode-4-5)

Comment: Thanks, but Which file I mentioned to use these macros? I need use HelloWorld class.

Comment: in .h file. I have also put the reference link. Please visit it.

Comment: it should be `__cplusplus`

Comment: Thank your solution, but I wanna use some enum in this cpp file.It only works in some time. It's not the problem's essence.

Comment: So hide the C++ standard library classes within the `.mm` file and don't mention them in the `.h` file.  Create an enumeration semantic that doesn't use the C++ standard library semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat 's answer.

It has only one standard solution, that's make compiler knows about specified sources should be compiled as objective-c++.

There are only 3 ways:

1. change .m to .mm
2. change Type to Objective-c++ in Utilities panel in xcode editor.
3. change "Compile sources as" to objective-c++

If you import cpp file indirectly, you should change all files to objective-c++ compiled mode on the import chain.

Comment: So your solution is to compile all your Objective-C files as Objective-C++?  That is a poor solution and better solutions are available.